# Stuffed Animal In OpenGL

Tags: glsl

I have seen metal/plastic/water/fire/... shaders for OpenGL.

However, it it possible to render something fur-like, say a stuffed animal / teddy bear in OpenGL (I know this is possible with renderman / ray tracers, but I want to do it in OpenGl).

If you have pointers to GLSl shaders for this, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

[I'm guessing the answer is no since fur requires more than just shaders -- it almost requires creating geometry on the fly -- but I'd love to be proven wrong)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[here](http://www.xbdev.net/directx3dx/specialX/Fur/index.php) is a nice tutorial about creating fur in 3d.

Comment: This is genius. Correct me if I'm wrong. The idea is that say I have to render a field of 100x100 = 10000 blades of grass. Instead of using a few triangles per blade of grass, I pick 10 heights that slice _all_ the blades of grass. Then, I just render these 10 "shells", where each "shell" has parts of each 10000 blade, but at a particular cross-section/height.